# Qt - How to expand or Collapse my QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qt4.7, qt4.8, qpushbutton

I have a **QTableView** with some items in it. If **i click on any row**, that particular **row has to expand with some QPushButtons** in it. I had attached the screen shot of it. How can i achieve this? Need ur help. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: Would a two-level-depth [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#details) with multiple columns be an alternative?

Comment: This is not possible with a `QTableView`. As Andreas pointed out you should use a `QTreeView` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be done with [QML](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html).

If you check out the [Models and Views: ListView Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-modelviews-listview.html), the expanding delegates example does exactly what you need.

The picture that you describe above could be built in QML as [QML ListView](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-listview.html) with embedded [QML Row Elements](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-row.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i dont want it to be done with QML. Can you plz suggest me a solution with Qt/C++ itself.

Comment: @stackunderflow thanks. 4 years later, your answer saved me lots of time. I tried to do this with tableview's rowDelegate, but apparently it is simply not designed for something like this.